# Chef using variable to set value in template

Tags: chef-infra

I need to set the external IP of the server in a template file. The server is behind a NAT so I was going to use a static file which I will keep updated. This file will contain the local IP and related external IP. Examples are below.

But I need a way of returning the variable value and applying it into my template file. I'm just stuck on how to go about this. I'm guessing I set this in my attribute file somehow referencing the local IP to my static file.

server file:

```
192.168.10.1=88.54.45.15
192.168.10.2=88.54.45.16
192.168.10.2=88.54.45.17
192.168.10.3=88.54.45.18
```

Current template file(This correctly brings back the local IP, so I need to then use this as a lookup to fine the external IP):

```
data="local_ip_v4=<%= @local_ip_v4 %>"
data="external_sip_ip=UNSURE WHAT TO PUT HERE"/
```

I have now used a databag below is setup:

Databag is called freeswitch and contains:
    `{
      "192.168.1.1": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.15"
  },
  "192.168.1.2": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.16"
  },
  "192.168.1.3": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.17"
  },
  "192.168.1.4": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.18"
  },
  "192.168.1.5": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.19"
  },
  "192.168.1.6": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.20"
  },
  "192.168.1.7": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.21"
  },
  "192.168.1.8": {
    "extip": "88.54.45.22"
  },
  "id": "extaddress"
}`

Recipe has:

```
data = data_bag_item( 'freeswitch', 'extaddress' )
template "/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/vars.conf.xml" do
source "vars.conf.xml.erb"
mode 0644
variables( :exitip => data[[node['freeswitch']['local_ip']]['extip']] )
end
```

It the variables section I'm having trouble formatting. FYI I have an attribute which is ['freeswitch']['local_ip'].

Error I receive now is :

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/freeswitch/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/freeswitch/recipes/default.rb:31:in `block in from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/freeswitch/recipes/default.rb:28:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/freeswitch/recipes/default.rb:

 24:    mode 0644
 25:  end
 26:
 27:  data = data_bag_item( 'freeswitch', 'extaddress' )[node['freeswitch']['local_ip']]
 28:  template "/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/vars.conf.xml" do
 29:    source "vars.conf.xml.erb"
 30:    mode 0644
 31>>   variables( :exitip => data[node['freeswitch']['local_ip']]['extip'] )
 32:  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to solve this. Some which are easy ones to retrieve and pass to template variables, are:

1. Store the pair in data bags and fetch accordingly in recipe.

   ```
    data_bag_item("a", "b")['192.168.10.1']
   ```
2. Store in some json file in key value format and use File handling
   and ***JSON*** gem to extract specific values.

   ```
   JSON.load(File.read("file.json"))['192.168.10.1']
   ```
3. Store as property file and use File handling and ***parseconfig*** gem
   to extract specific values.

   ```
   ParseConfig.new("file.properties")['192.168.10.1']
   ```

To access your databag "extip", it should be:

```
variables( :exitip => data[node['freeswitch']['local_ip']]['extip'] )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you have specified the ip address but I can not put this in my recipes as I don't know the local IP until the script is ran. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Usually, You can use node['ipaddress'] in recipes to get internal IP of the machine, otherwise you can check in ohai data.

Comment: I decided to use a databag, but the nodeIP I'm having issues on how to declare it in the code please see below variables.

data = data_bag_item( 'freeswitch', 'extip' )
template "/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/vars.conf.xml" do
  source "vars.conf.xml.erb"
  mode 0644
  variables( :exitip => data[node['ipaddress']['extip'] )
end

Comment: Can you update your question. Its tough to understand from comment section.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting the error which I have updated my issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Its very plain as you are fetching node['freeswitch']['local_ip'] twice from the data bag. it should be like:
data = data_bag_item( 'freeswitch', 'extaddress' )
And, in template: variables( :exitip => data[node['freeswitch']['local_ip']]['extip'] )

Comment: Oh my bad. The test server I'm using I didnt put he IP in the databag!